# Issue with xmlattributes and clob in oracle 11g

Tags: xml, oracle11g

I need to use `CLOB` field as `XML` Attributes but getting

`error ORA-00932 :inconsistent datatypes: expected-got CLOB.`

Used data length is always greater than 4k so i can not use any other data type.

```
Column Used:
EMAIL_SUBJECT_BODY CLOB()
    XMLELEMENT("Field" ,
        XMLATTRIBUTES(
            'Email_Subject_Body' AS "name" ,
            EMAIL_SUBJECT_BODY AS "value"
    )
ERROR:   ORA-00932 :inconsistent datatypes: expected-got CLOB
```

It work fine with:

```
SELECT TO_CLOB(EMAIL_SUBJECT_BODY) FROM TNAME;
SELECT XMLELEMENT("test", EMAIL_SUBJECT_BODY) FROM TNAME;
```

But fails with:

```
SELECT XMLELEMENT("test", XMLATTRIBUTES(EMAIL_SUBJECT_BODY AS "a")) FROM TNAME;
```

I'm using `Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.1.0.7.0 - 64bit Production`.

Any clue how can i resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use values of length > 4000 with XMLELEMENT or XMLATTRIBUTES, its documented limitation.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions220.htm

A few options are:

1. Store your data as XML so you don't have to use the Oracle API to
   convert
2. Change the CLOB to an XMLType column, then use the
   XMLType API which does have clob support.
3. Use an external XML API (.NET, Java). I actually prefer .NET's API to Oracle's.
4. Old fashioned way, create the XML with concatenation and a few REPLACE calls to take care of escaping.

I originally thought you should be able to get away with PL/SQL to use the full VARCHAR2(32767) but I tried  with no luck. There is a popular example out on Google/OTN that looks good at first glance, but the problem with that example is it uses a trivially small string. The author failed to test it with > 4K values. Once over 4K, this also fails :

```
declare
  body  varchar2(32767);
  xml clob;
begin
  select email_subject_body into body from email where rownum = 1;
  -- THIS FAILS TOO
  select XMLELEMENT("test", XMLATTRIBUTES(body AS "a")).GETCLOBVAL() INTO xml FROM DUAL; 
end;
/

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested
ORA-06512: at line 6
```

I included it here just to show you.

Comment: Thanks for response. changed my clob column to xmltype and found it can hold up to 4k char only mine requirement is ~13k.

Comment: XMLType isn't limited to 4K. Somewhere you are must be doing an intermediate step or implicit conversion to cause a char/varchar context. What is the execution environment for this program? Is it a sqlplus script, or is it a web application or utility written in another language? If you go directly from XMLType to CLOB, there is no size limit.